# find words in two quotes unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I would like to display the last word in these lines I tried to look for example the word value but no answer, so I thought to look for the words between quotes but my file contains other words between quotes that I have I need not actually want to display the values ​​of the select tag knowing that my html file is.

```
grep '*' hosts.html | awk '{print $NF}'
```

For example:

```
value='www.visit-tunisia.com'>www.visit-tunisia.com 
value='www.watania1.tn'>www.watania1.tn 
value='www.watania2.tn'>www.watania2.tn
```

I would have

```
www.visit-tunisia.com 
www.watania1.tn 
www.watania2.tn
```

Comment: Please restate your question, perhaps showing some sample lines of input and the expected output. You updated it to include the `www.watania2.tn` information, but that still isn't very clear.  Are you looking for the same 'name' appearing twice on a single line, once inside single quotes?

Comment: I have several online I would have as a result for exemple 
value='www.visit-tunisia.com'>www.visit-tunisia.com
value='www.watania1.tn'>www.watania1.tn
value='www.watania2.tn'>www.watania2.tn
I would have www.visit-tunisia.com                                           www.watania1.tn                                                                        www.watania2.tn please

Comment: Please update the question with this new information, where you can use the formatting to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field separator to `>` you do this with the `-F` option:

```
$ awk -F'>' '{print $NF}' hosts.html
www.visit-tunisia.com
www.watania1.tn
www.watania2.tn
```

Note: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by `grep '*' hosts.html`?

Comment: @user1794019 if this answers was the most helpful please upvote and **[accept it by clicking the tick mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)** next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the comment liberally, you have input lines which might contain:

```
value='www.visit-tunisia.com'>www.visit-tunisia.com
value='www.watania1.tn'>www.watania1.tn
value='www.watania2.tn'>www.watania2.tn
```

and you would like the names which are repeated on a line as the output:

```
www.visit-tunisia.com
www.watania1.tn
www.watania2.tn
```

This can be done using `sed` and capturing parentheses.

```
sed -n -e "s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*\1.*/\1/p"
```

The `-n` says "don't print unless I say to do so".  The `s///p` command prints if the substitute works.  The pattern looks for a stream of 'anything' (`.*`), a single quote, captures what's inside up to the next single quote (`'\([^']*\)'`) followed by any text, the captured text (the first `\1`), and anything.  The replacement text is what was captured (the second `\1`).

Example:

```
$ cat data
www and wotnot
value='www.visit-tunisia.com'>www.visit-tunisia.com
blah
value='www.watania1.tn'>www.watania1.tn
hooplah
value='www.watania2.tn'>www.watania2.tn
if 'nothing' is required, nothing will be done.
$ sed -n -e "s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*\1.*/\1/p" data
www.visit-tunisia.com
www.watania1.tn
www.watania2.tn
nothing
$
```

Clearly, you can refine the `[^']*` part of the match if you want to.  I used double quotes around the expression since the pattern matches on single quotes.  Life is trickier if you need to allow both single and double quotes; at that point, I'd put the script into a file and run `sed -f script data` to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*>\(.*\)/\1/g' your_file
```